# How to use scalar type as function argument in gRPC?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

In gRPC, it expects the argument to be a protobuf message.
Suppose I want to send an int, I have to create a message `message Int { int32 value = 1; }` and use this message to send an int.

Here is an example of the function definition: `rpc Range(Int) returns (stream Int) {}`

But I don't want to be creating a message structure like this for every default scalar type e.g. bool, int32, int64, float, etc.
How do I use a scalar type in gRPC function argument?

Comment: You might be looking for Value in struct.proto? It handles many common types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protobuf provides wrapper types, you can use `Int32Value`.

it should look like this

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service YourSerice {
  rpc Range(google.protobuf.Int32Value) returns (stream google.protobuf.Int32Value) {}
}
```

You can check other primitive wrappers on protobuf github ([wrappers.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto#L88)).

Comment: Thank you. I have done the changes you suggested but it seems the `Int32Value` does not exist. It said `Import google/protobuf/wrappers.proto but not used.` and `"Int32Value" is not defined.` I use `python -m grpc_tools.protoc` to compile the proto file. And `grpcio` version is `1.27.2`. How do I check which messages are defined in the `wrappers.proto`? i.e. where is this wrappers file?

Comment: i wasn't use fully qualified name, updated the snippet. can you try again?

Comment: Yes. it's working now. But it's quite long to type. Is there a way to make this short? And how can I access this `Int32Value` message in my python code? Is it going to be accessed the same like `helloworld_pb2.Int()`?

Comment: i don't think there's a way to make it short. i am not using python, so i don't know exact syntax. you can treat it just like any other message. you need to access the `value` field of the `Int32Value`.